# ARM Cortex-M4 toolchain

Tags: eclipse, gcc, arm, cortex-m, toolchain

Is there a way to setup Eclipse + gnu gcc + debugger for the ARM Cortex-M3/M4 based microprocessors (e.g., Stellaris, Kinetis)?

Comment: Note that there is a gcc cross-compiler with support from ARM at https://launchpad.net/gcc-linaro It has worked well for me programming Cortex-M0, -M3, and -M4 devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If toolchain is gcc based and debugger gdb based, then probably yes. 
Just use eclipse with CDT, set up cross compile project, enter toolchain prefix (like arm-eabi- or something) etc... 
When compiled use create "gdb hardware debugging" launch configuration, enter proper gdb command to use (probably something-gdb) and you will probably be fine.

Comment: If you say "If toolchain is gcc": so is there any other way around?

Comment: I've got CDT/Eclipse but I am not able setup cross compile project.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's installed by default. Go to help menu, then "install new software" and select "c/c++ gcc cross compiler support" in "Mobile and Device development" category. Install it, then it should be available (in new C project/executable/Cross GCC).

Comment: Unfortunately, my ECLIPSE Helios does not show any item within  "install new software"

Comment: You need to select "sites" to search. Just select all available sites.

Answer (score 0):

According to ["Programming the Stellaris Launchpad with GNU/Linux"](http://recursive-labs.com/blog/2012/10/28/stellaris-launchpad-gnu-linux-getting-started/), you can use [lm4tools](https://github.com/utzig/lm4tools)
 for the target, [summon-arm-toolchain](https://github.com/esden/summon-arm-toolchain) to get the compiler and even use [Stellarisware](http://www.ti.com/tool/sw-ek-lm4f120xl). There's also [jsnyder's gcc project](https://github.com/jsnyder/arm-eabi-toolchain) on github.

I'm in the process of finding a suitable toolchain as well, but will not touch Eclipse or any messy installers. For that path, you may want to look at [CodeSourcery](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Installing_CodeSourcery_Toolchain). Eclipse comes with the trial cersion. I'm not looking for Kinetis at the moment myself. There's also [Yagarto](http://www.yagarto.de/) for mswin and OSX.

There is some [talk about interfacing to the Stellaris debugger](http://forum.stellarisiti.com/topic/309-icdi-support-in-openocd/). The [lmicdiusb, "TCP/USB bridge created by T"I](https://github.com/utzig/lm4tools) should let GDB communicate with the Stellaris Launchpad ICDI. I'm not yet sure how tied that is to the particular board or chip.

Update: I've found that the [Emdebian toolchains](http://wiki.debian.org/EmdebianToolchain) work perfectly well for Cortex (Thumb) targets. Stellarisware and CMSIS build essentially out of the box (with the right compiler name set). These are integrated and (for Debian) thus the cleanest way to get the toolchain. I believe on Ubuntu, you have the same arm compilers in main.

Update: [Debian now has a "bare metal" compiler in the main distribution](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/gcc-arm-none-eabi). It is [working well for me](http://xtl.kapsi.fi/stellaris.html) and should have the neatest integration into other tools.

Comment: Just for the record, didn't TI drop the Stellaris line a long time ago?

Comment: @JoeHass I haven't noticed if they completely dropped it. The Cortex M4F line was renamed to Tiva-C.